# What's the difference between these two sets?

Tags: trigonometry

Given the sets $A=\{x\in \Bbb R | x \in[0,2\pi]\}$ and $B=\{x\in \Bbb R | x \in[-\pi,\pi]\}$, solve the equation $\cos(x)=\frac {1}{2}$ within them.

I know the answer varies because of the period, but what's the difference between the intervals $[0,2\pi]$ and $[-\pi,\pi]$? Doesn't the answer $\frac {\pi}{3}$ satisfy both conditions?

Comment: $[0, 2\pi] =$ all $x$ s.t. $0 \le x \le 2\pi$.  $[-\pi, \pi] = $ all $y$ s.t.. $-\pi \le y \le \pi]$.  As $0 < \pi/3 < \pi$ it follows $\pi/3 \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\pi/3 \in [-\pi, \pi]$.  But $-\pi/3 \not \in [0,2\pi]$ and $5\pi/3 \not \in [-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: Okay.  A={x∈R|x∈[0,2π]} means nothing more or less than A = [0,2pi].  and B={x∈R|x∈[−π,π]} means nothing more or less than B = [-pi,pi].  And yes pi/3 is in both sets.  But there are two other solutions that are in one but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for $\cos x = 1/2; x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ is the set $\{-\pi/3, \pi/3\}$.

The solution for $\cos x = 1/2; x \in [0, 2\pi]$ is the set $\{\pi/3, 5\pi/3\}$.

$\pi/3 \in [0,2\pi] \cap [-\pi, \pi]$.

$-\pi/3 \in  [-\pi, \pi]; -\pi/3 \not \in [0,2\pi]$

$5\pi/3 \in  [0, 2\pi]; 5\pi/3 \not \in [-\pi,\pi]$

$[0,2\pi] = [0,\pi] \cup [\pi, 2\pi]$

$[-\pi, \pi] = [-\pi,0] \cup [0,\pi]$

$[0,2\pi]\cap [-\pi, \pi]= [0,\pi]$.